# Running instances of the same exe (on a shared drive) on two separate servers?

Tags: network-shares

I am automating a lab where the same tests are conducted on separate test servers (using the same GUI). The executable for that GUI lives with the source code on a network drive that both servers have access to.

If shortcuts are created for both of the different servers to launch instances of that executable, can I expect to see any problems?

Currently it appears that one of the machines is unable to run the executable from the shortcut to the drive location, so I ended up placing it on the server itself. The other server runs the executable on the network drive from it's shortcut without issues.

I'm not an IT wiz so I am sure there many other things I have not considered.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can run an application (.exe) on a remote share with no issues.  However, this depends entirely on how the application was written.  If the application is programmed to write data to its *local* directory, running the same application in two remote places could cause the data it is trying to write to collide and cause issues.  If you are unable to run it from two remote locations, signs point to the fact that something along those lines is occurring.

Comment: thanks for the response. The application itself is writing data to a network sql server, so I'd imagine that isn't the issue. It does pull testing scripts from it's local file location, but the paths to those scripts called by the application's settings file are the same on both machines (but each is pulling from itself), and there aren't any "can't find file" type of errors popping up.